# Subquery returned more than 1 value when getting different employee_id

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to get the employee id for different employees based on the column xmlreqbody :

```
select substring( (select   right (xmlreqbody,61) from FAILEDXMLBODY), 0,10)
```

Comment: Can you share your input/desired output?

Comment: how many rows do you get when you execute `select right (xmlreqbody,61) from FAILEDXMLBODY`

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to get the first 10 chars of the 61 rightmost chars of the column:

```
select 
  substring( 
    right(xmlreqbody, 61), 
    1,
    10
  )
from FAILEDXMLBODY
```

Comment: ...or `select left(right(xmlreqbody, 61), 10) from FAILEDXMLBODY`

Comment: @ZoharPeled sure, it's the same.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
 SELECT SUBSTRING(RIGHT(xmlreqbody,61), 0,10) FROM FAILEDXMLBODY
```